# How to embed youtube video in mvc3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, embed

How can i embed youtube url into my cshtml page.
I tried to embed url like this but its not working.

I tried to pass url but its showing me nothing.

```
My url is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S8a180uYBM

<object width="400" height="250">
<param name="movie" value="@Model.url"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<embed src="@Model.url" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="250" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
```

If i change my url like this its working fine.

```
<object width="400" height="250">
<param name="movie" value="@Model.url"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/3S8a180uYBM?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="250" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
```

But how can i change my url

from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S8a180uYBM

to http://www.youtube.com/v/3S8a180uYBM?version=3

By going to http://www.youtube.com/ searching any video it will give url like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S8a180uYBM  only

How can i convert it to url like http://www.youtube.com/v/3S8a180uYBM?version=3

Using javascript or jquery?

Comment: without the api support i dont think you can modify the url like that

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a regex (this is in js, but there are regexes in pretty much all the languages).

```
text = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S8a180uYBM';
new_text = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' + text.match(/v=(.+)$/)[1] + "?version=3";
```